# Django double inner join with mysql slow

Tags: mysql, sql, django, join

Why is this query slow in Django using MySQL?
I have three models I'm filtering on that relate to each other with a OneToOne and ForeignKey. The following query on my DB with approximately 60k rows takes about 300 seconds to complete.

```
resutls = A.objects.filter(b__c__candy__icontains="gummybears")
results  # <-- 300 seconds
```

The models in app:

```
class A(models.Model):
    b = models.OneToOneField(B, default=None)
    a_charfield = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='')

class B(models.Model):
    b_charfield = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='')
    primary_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, primary_key=True, default='', null=False)

class C(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey('B')
    candy = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=40, default='')
```

Printing the result.query shows the MySQL query as (I combined the column names to *):

```
SELECT *
FROM `app_a` 
INNER JOIN `app_b` ON (`app_a`.`b_id` = `app_b`.`primary_id`) 
INNER JOIN `app_c` ON (`app_b`.`primary_id` = `app_c`.`b_id`) 
WHERE `app_c`.`candy` LIKE %gummybears%  
ORDER BY `app_a`.`id` DESC
```

I have two working solutions.

1. get the results from B as a values_list and use as a filter arg to A.
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in  Performance considerations

   ```
   resutls = A.objects.filter(b__in=list(B.objects.filter(c__c_charfield__icontains="candy").values_list('pk', flat=True))
   ```
2. switch to postgresql. The double inner join worked < 1 sec

Comment: use also `select_related()`

Comment: Could you run an EXPLAIN with that MySQL error? Maybe you're missing an index on one of the foreign keys?

Answer (score 0):

The leading % in the following code forces the query to do a full table scan instead of using an index.  If the candy table does not fit in memory that is going to take a while.

```
WHERE `app_c`.`candy` LIKE %gummybears%
```

See the documentation under [B-Tree Index Characteristics](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)